# How does @context_processor effect template variables?

Tags: python, flask

I found the following code:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user():
    if authed():
        return dict(session)
    return dict()
```

Then they use `session['nonce'] = XXXXX` and use the `{{ nonce }}` in a template.

If I define a var in a context processor, do I know all of its attributes?  Is `{{ nonce }}` the same as the session value?

I concluded that the `session` var is passed to all the templates, but it's not clear if its attributes are also known, and if so isn't it supposed to be used as `session.nonce` instead of `nonce`?

Answer (score 2):

Flask passes the `session` to the template context by default.  This can be used just like in your view code, it is a dictionary.

```
{{ session['nonce'] }}
or {{ session.nonce }}
```

The context processor your posted takes all the items from the session and puts them directly in the template context, so they don't *have* to be accessed through the `session` var.

```
{{ nonce }} comes from session through the context processor
```

Ultimately, the context processor you posted is pretty useless, but it could be convenient in some cases.